# Cual es el equivalente de la función de C# UTF8Encoding(string) en PHP?

Tags: php, c#, urlencoding

Estoy intentando usar la función utf8_encode(string) en mi programa de PHP pero no me devuelve el mismo contenido que en el programa en C#. A qué se debe esto? Necesito que en PHP me devuelva el mismo string que en el codigo de C#, ya que el error me lo da con la salida de la funcion de encoding de PHP pero con la de C# sí me va bien.

Esta es la salida de la función PHP utf8_encode que no me funciona luego:

```
utf8_encode($encrypted): Z2OpXIkFMkKx6FkfxTCbsnP+d0AvgP6FGbMZG2grNH0UAIkSOcxwGT83cO/W9ZFxTPLZtdATIi1X5J0I8sigGOIryuMpWUYliCw5UCNOLSIetrKJrSFHe2cofriPNMLXlO2w/DWNYoKtHRer66G+ErBBaQMCw0MXW9qgvGxqNr0TkS5abH0/ezmq9BDtV6bo02ea5TQtM5haGLO98ThF9SAxCj+8CfmUd8av92Drovl4t/L30EJjQXd05lwvTsMPaDjG9c2Ofaal5HhE3zuL6GwGN298Vw2txBuWDUe2TjLlMn+o9duuMVUQUAukck2a2MwTe1QElgU8flWQC6aldx9JYm4NOZHO8AzTNyRFvSdqeHR5oKFHXS8vcDx5R8kakEbjdS5gL3my3SNUMt2EZZffZ8mRshUFEDe/f3RSyPiF3UzPUVeQZoCl2jvvanJ4Y3OSqpmJqjtw+drQ1clIx4h5td58CVu6PaJPdE7C94U=
```

Y esto es lo que me devuelve la de C# que sí que me funciona, necesito que la de PHP me devuelva esto mismo:

```
UTF8Encoding(encrypted): Z2OpXIkFMkKx6FkfxTCbsnP%2Bd0AvgP6FGbMZG2grNH0UAIkSOcxwGT83cO%2FW9ZFxTPLZtdATIi1X5J0I8sigGOIryuMpWUYliCw5UCNOLSIetrKJrSFHe2cofriPNMLXlO2w%2FDWNYoKtHRer66G%2BErBBaQMCw0MXW9qgvGxqNr0TkS5abH0%2Fezmq9BDtV6bo02ea5TQtM5haGLO98ThF9SAxCj%2B8CfmUd8av92Drovl4t%2FL30EJjQXd05lwvTsMPaDjG9c2Ofaal5HhE3zuL6GwGN298Vw2txBuWDUe2TjLlMn%2Bo9duuMVUQUAukck2a2MwTe1QElgU8flWQC6aldx9JYm4NOZHO8AzTNyRFvSdqeHR5oKFHXS8vcDx5R8kakEbjdS5gL3my3SNUMt2EZZffZ8mRshUFEDe%2Ff3RSyPiF3UzPUVeQZoCl2jvvanJ4Y3OSqpmJqjtw%2BdrQ1clIx4h5td58CVu6PaJPdE7C94U%3D
```

Comment: Hola, estás en StackOverflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta o trasládala al sitio en Inglés.

Comment: Vale ya lo he traducido perdona

Answer (score 0):

Si te das cuenta, la salida de `utf8_encode()` es similar a la de `UTF8Encoding()` por no decir que es la misma por el único detalle que en PHP los carácteres no están codificados (se muestra `+` en lugar de `%2B`, y así con los demás carácteres).

Por lo que bastaría con usar la función [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) para hacer que la salida sea igual a la que obtienes con C#.

```php
$str = "Z2OpXIkFMkKx6FkfxTCbsnP+d0AvgP6FGbMZG2grNH0UAIkSOcxwGT83cO/W9ZFxTPLZtdATIi1X5J0I8sigGOIryuMpWUYliCw5UCNOLSIetrKJrSFHe2cofriPNMLXlO2w/DWNYoKtHRer66G+ErBBaQMCw0MXW9qgvGxqNr0TkS5abH0/ezmq9BDtV6bo02ea5TQtM5haGLO98ThF9SAxCj+8CfmUd8av92Drovl4t/L30EJjQXd05lwvTsMPaDjG9c2Ofaal5HhE3zuL6GwGN298Vw2txBuWDUe2TjLlMn+o9duuMVUQUAukck2a2MwTe1QElgU8flWQC6aldx9JYm4NOZHO8AzTNyRFvSdqeHR5oKFHXS8vcDx5R8kakEbjdS5gL3my3SNUMt2EZZffZ8mRshUFEDe/f3RSyPiF3UzPUVeQZoCl2jvvanJ4Y3OSqpmJqjtw+drQ1clIx4h5td58CVu6PaJPdE7C94U=";

$encoded = "Z2OpXIkFMkKx6FkfxTCbsnP%2Bd0AvgP6FGbMZG2grNH0UAIkSOcxwGT83cO%2FW9ZFxTPLZtdATIi1X5J0I8sigGOIryuMpWUYliCw5UCNOLSIetrKJrSFHe2cofriPNMLXlO2w%2FDWNYoKtHRer66G%2BErBBaQMCw0MXW9qgvGxqNr0TkS5abH0%2Fezmq9BDtV6bo02ea5TQtM5haGLO98ThF9SAxCj%2B8CfmUd8av92Drovl4t%2FL30EJjQXd05lwvTsMPaDjG9c2Ofaal5HhE3zuL6GwGN298Vw2txBuWDUe2TjLlMn%2Bo9duuMVUQUAukck2a2MwTe1QElgU8flWQC6aldx9JYm4NOZHO8AzTNyRFvSdqeHR5oKFHXS8vcDx5R8kakEbjdS5gL3my3SNUMt2EZZffZ8mRshUFEDe%2Ff3RSyPiF3UzPUVeQZoCl2jvvanJ4Y3OSqpmJqjtw%2BdrQ1clIx4h5td58CVu6PaJPdE7C94U%3D";

echo urlencode($str) == $encoded ? "Iguales": "No iguales";
// Iguales
```